# google analytics product data with demographic dimension

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, gtag.js

Currently i have an ecommerce site being tracked by google analytics, implemented with gtag.js.

here's what i was trying to do :

- get product-related data form enhanced ecommerce reports with demographic dimensions in Reporting API

e.g.

- request metrics : product detailed view, product checkouts, product added to carts, item quantity, purchased value
- along with following dimension : product sku + gender + age + device + browser

here's what i've done so far :

- enable [ Enable Demographics and Interest Reports ] in [ Property Settings ], in Google Analytics GUI
- enable [ Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Reporting ] in [ View Settings ], in Google Analytics GUI
- enable [ Enable Ecommerce ] in [ View Settings ], in Google Analytics GUI
- test whether current request is fine with the dimension & metric explorer ( link ) -> think it is a valid combination

results i'm getting so far :

- can get ecommerce data with the following combination of dimensions : ( browser + gender + age + device + time )
- cannot get ecommerce data with the following combination of dimensions : ( sku + browser + gender + age + device + time )

i don't think adding a ga('require', 'displayfeatures');  code would help, since i implemented by using gtag.js...

( related link : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?authuser=1 )

and ideas? or points to give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with **Dimensions & Metrics Explorer** (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) this combination of dimensions is questionable: sku + browser + gender + age + device + time.

However, when analyzing users based on age, gender and interest categories it should be taken into account that this data, in Google Analytics, is only available to a subset of users (https://www.analyticstraps.com/i-report-con-i-dati-demografici-non-tornano/).

Also, the documentation **About Demographics and Interests** says:

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a report, then data for the male value may be withheld.
> These thresholds are system defined, and you cannot adjust them.
> If a threshold has been applied to a report, you will see a notice below the report title.

For this reason, when you use one of the demographic reports as a dimension, the data is no longer complete.